# Projections correspond to double duals of $C(X)$-algebras fibers

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Let $A$ be a $C(X)$-algebra ($X$ compact).
For $x\neq y$ in $X$, we have the Glimm ideals in $A$:
$I=C_0(X\setminus \{x\})A$ and $J=C_0(X\setminus \{y\})A$.
The fibers are denoted by $A_x=A/I$ and $A_y=A/J$.
Choose central projections $p,q\in A^{**}$ satisfying:
$I^{**}=pA^{**}$ and $J^{**}=qA^{**}$.
It follows that $A_x^{**}=(1-p)A^{**}$ and $A_y^{**}= (1-q)A^{**}$.

I want to show that $1-p$ and $1-q$ are orthogonal projections.

Probably one has to look on representation of $A$ that vanish on the distinct Glimm ideals $I$ and $J$ and to extend them to representations on the double duals.

I would be happy for any help!
Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by a $C(X)$-algebra? A Banach algebra that is also $C(X)$-bimodular and for which the multiplication is $C(X)$-bimodular?

Comment: @Adrián: yes and no. There is a "twist". A $C(X)$-algebra is a C$^*$-algebra $A$ such that there is a unital $*$-homomorphism $\rho:C(X)\to Z(M(A))$. It is a standard notion in the world of C$^*$-algebras.